# How to find exact (minimum) elements from array to match given sum

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum, knapsack-problem

I want a method which return minimum element array to match the given sum

```
def find_elements arr, sum
  #logic here
end
```

Examples

```
arr = [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
find_elements arr, 50 #should return [50]
find_elements arr, 100 #should return [60, 40]
```

Note:- If no combination matches with the sum, find the min elements which are close to the sum & less than sum

```
find_elements arr, 75 #should return [60, 10]
```

Comment: This looks like exact [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: @Marek, I don’t think so, as the OP wants to find the “minimum element subarray to match the given sum” (provided such a subarray exists), which, unlike the knapsack problem, is NP-complete.

Comment: @Salil - How [60, 10] or [60, 40] is a subarray?

Comment: Whether you want a method, do not hesitate to _write_ it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland not exactly: 'Note:- If no combination matches with the sum, find the min elements which are close to the sum & less than sum'

Comment: @Surya :- I mean array, i want [60,10] as an o/p

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin :- Yes, i have just wrote it. Not sure about its performance & any edge case which i might forgot.

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity. Probably not the most performant one.

```
knapsack = ->(arr, sum) do
  arr = arr.reject(&sum.method(:<)).sort.reverse
  (1..arr.size).reduce([]) do |acc, i|
    result =
      arr.combination(i).reduce([]) do |acc, comb|
        curr = comb.sum
        break comb if curr == sum
        (curr > acc.sum and curr < sum) ? comb : acc
      end
    curr = result.sum
    break result if curr == sum
    (curr > acc.sum and curr < sum) ? result : acc
  end
end
```

Smoke test.

```
knapsack.([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 50)
#⇒ [50]
knapsack.([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 110)
#⇒ [60, 50]
knapsack.([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 90)
#⇒ [60, 30]
knapsack.([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 75)
#⇒ [60, 10]
knapsack.([10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 500)
#⇒ [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way of doing it ? more efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like following, which is working fine (Not sure if i am missing any edge case though)

```
class Array
  def head_tail
    head, *tail = *self
    [head, tail]
  end
end

def find_elements array, sum
  head, tail = array.head_tail
  return unless head
  if head < sum
    [ head, *find_elements(tail, (sum - head))]
  elsif head == sum
    head
  elsif head > sum
    find_elements(tail, sum)
  end
end
```

Where array elements are in descending order like `array = [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10]`